# Docker Compose bind mount doesn't work in GitHub Actions

Tags: docker-compose, github-actions

If I run a Docker Compose command in GitHub Actions which uses a bind mount, it says the source directory doesn't exist. Here's the error.

```
Cannot create container for service chat: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /__w/omni-chat/omni-chat
```

I think the issue is that the root directory is incorrectly being passed to GitHub Actions. I specified the absolute path as the conventional `.`, but I don't know what caveats GitHub Actions has regarding that.

Here's a simplified version of my workflow.

```yaml
on: push
jobs:
  test-server:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: docker/compose
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: docker-compose run --rm chat gradle test
```

Here's a simplified version of my Docker Compose file.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  chat:
    image: gradle:6.3-jdk8
    command: bash
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /home/gradle
      - type: volume
        source: gradle-cache
        target: /home/gradle/.gradle
volumes:
  gradle-cache:
```

If you need the full details, here's the [exact run](https://github.com/neelkamath/omni-chat/actions/runs/65646164).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you should use preinstalled Docker Compose installation. So simply removing the specified `container` will allow bind mounts to work since it's no longer a Docker-in-Docker scenario.