# docker-compose does not create directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have the following docker-compose

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
   foo:
      image: an_image
      volumes:
         - source: ./logs
           target: /tmp/data
           type: bind
```

I am using 3.9 docker-compose syntax with 2.24 docker-compose library. Because [of this bug](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/654) I have to use the long syntax for mounting volumes.

My goal is the following: The `logs` directory does not exist in the host system. Nevertheless, I want to create this directory and mount it on the docker container. With the old binary version this was working (I was using the compact syntax ./logs:/tmp/data) but not anymore and not with the long syntax.

The error I am getting is

```
Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /host_mnt/Users/user/Workspace/an-app/e2e/logs
```

I am running docker-compose from the an-app directory

```
docker-compose -f ./e2e/docker-compose.e2e.yml up
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you can use `create_host_path`, like so:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
   foo:
      image: an_image
      volumes:
         - source: ./logs
           target: /tmp/data
           type: bind
           bind:
               create_host_path: true
```

Reference: [Long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#long-syntax-5):

> create_host_path: Creates a directory at the source path on host if there is nothing present. Compose does nothing if there is something present at the path. This is automatically implied by short syntax for backward compatibility with docker-compose legacy.

Comment: I am upvoting. It does work on my local setup but unfortunately not on my GitHub actions CI. Once I also make it work on my CI, I can accept it as an answer. Thanks @FirstOne –

Comment: There was no mention of GitHub Actions in the original post. I'd say my answer provides a solution to it as is. Maybe this is the case for another question, @Niko

Comment: Just as a bonus, I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60910436/4577762) which seems related, @Niko. BTW, I won't continue discussing this in comments since there is nothing about GitHub Actions in the question nor the answer, and maybe there is a particularity about it unrelated to the content you posted. Hope you understand.

Comment: I had a similar issue to this where create_host_path being true still gave me an error about "source path does not exist". I think there's maybe been a subtle change since docker-compose 2.24 where if the source path has a trailing slash, create_host_path doesn't work. Maybe in your CI config has this problem? In any case your original issue has been resolved according to the Github link, so you can probably go back to short syntax which implies create_host_path: true.